# Add event to customer registration success

Tags: customer, session

I have a custom field in customer registration form which I want to add the value of it into a session variable called passcode. So far I have no success, what am I doing wrong?

```
<input type="text" name="passcode" id="passcode" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Passcode') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
```

Here is my observer

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $login = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams('passcode');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setPasscode($login);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass your field in `login array`

```
<input type="text" name="login[passcode]" id="passcode" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Passcode') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
```

in your observer

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $login = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setPasscode($login['passcode']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `getParams()` to `getParam()`:

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $login = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('passcode');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setPasscode($login);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that but it didn't work @SeStro

Comment: Check if anything is assigned to $login: "Mage::log($login, null, 'test.log', true);"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
print_r($postData['passcode']);
```

OR

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('passcode');
```